# I'm having a problem if the player dies but has clones of the same tool instead of all the clones saving only 1 does how can I fix this?

Tags: database, lua, scripting, game-development, roblox

My end achievement is wanting the duplicate tools to save when the player dies

For example, if the player owns three "Gun 1s" then dies instead of still having three Gun 1s in their inventory they will only have one Gun 1.

This is what I currently got

```
local Inventory = {}

local function Spawned(Char)
    local Plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Char)
    for i,v in pairs(Inventory[Plr]) do
        if Plr['Backpack']:findFirstChild(v.Name) then
            Plr['Backpack'][v.Name]:Destroy()
        end
        v.Parent = Plr['Backpack']  
    end
    Inventory[Plr] = {}
    Char:WaitForChild('Humanoid').Died:connect(function()
        for i,v in pairs({Plr['Backpack'], Char}) do
            for ii,vv in pairs(v:GetChildren()) do
                if vv:IsA('Tool') then
                    table.insert(Inventory[Plr], vv:Clone())
                    vv:Destroy()
                end
            end
        end
    end)
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(Plr)
    Inventory[Plr] = {}
    local Char = Plr.Character or Plr.CharacterAdded:wait()
    Spawned(Char)
    Plr.CharacterAdded:connect(Spawned)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are destroying the clones here.

```lua
if Plr['Backpack']:findFirstChild(v.Name) then
   Plr['Backpack'][v.Name]:Destroy()
end
```